# Case where numba.jit seems to have no effect on performance

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm running simple tests to see how efficient numba.jit is to improve the speed of loop functions with numpy arrays. However in both these examples:

```
def f():
    a=np.ones(1000)
    for i in range(100000):
        a+=np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
%time f()
```

and

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def g():
    a=np.ones(1000)
    for i in range(100000):
        a+=np.random.normal(0,1,1000)

%time g()
```

I get:

- CPU times: user 3.75 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.75 s
  Wall time: 3.75 s
- CPU times: user 3.86 s, sys: 4.11 ms, total: 3.86 s
  Wall time: 3.84 s

So numba.jit doesn't seem to have any effect in this case. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation, only the += operation can be optimized: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal

The call to the random number generator has a `size`, so it's not covered.

Most of the time is probably already done by numpy in an efficient manner, there isn't much numba can optimize in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear *why* you think there should be an improvement. I see an improvement by adding an inner loop with `numba`, which *may* be because JIT-compilation can optimise operations with more basic, lower-level types.

```
# python 3.6.0, numpy 1.11.3, numba 0.30.1

np.random.seed(0)

def f(m, n):
    a = np.ones(n)
    for i in range(m):
        a += np.random.normal(0,1,n)
    return a

@jit
def g(m, n):
    a = np.ones(n)
    for i in range(m):
        x = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
        for j in range(n):
            a[j] += x[j]
    return a

%timeit f(10**5, 10**3)  # 6.53 s per loop
%timeit g(10**5, 10**3)  # 4.68 s per loop
```